# Azure AD Graph API User memberOf nested groups

Tags: c#, azure, authorization, azure-active-directory

I am querying my Azure AD graph API for a user's group memberships.
I can make the query just fine, but the results are only the groups that the user DIRECTLY belongs to.  None of the nested groups are listed.

I'm trying to find out if a user belongs to a specific group, but I don't want to have to make, what could end up to be, over 100 api calls to find out. (i.e. a user belongs to GroupA which is a member of GroupB which is a member of GroupC which is a member of GroupD.  Groups B, C, and D do not show up in the user's list of groups even though he technically belongs to them - only GroupA).

Is there any way to get ALL group memberships in one API call or another?  When I was using Integrated Windows Authentication, the IsInRole(GroupD) would have returned true.  Though, that is not available with Azure AD authentication and any of the postings that claim to have code to re-implement IsInRole are simply making the same call to user.memberOf (which does not do the nested groups).

Just for reference, this is the code where I make the call.

```
var client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
var user = await client.Users.GetByObjectId(objectId).ExecuteAsync();
var userFetcher = (IUserFetcher)user;
var pagedCollection = await userFetcher.MemberOf.ExecuteAsync();

do
{
    var directoryObjects = pagedCollection.CurrentPage.ToList();

    foreach (var group in directoryObjects.OfType<Group>().Select(directoryObject => directoryObject))
    {
        groupMembership.Add(group);
    }

    pagedCollection = await pagedCollection.GetNextPageAsync();
}
while (pagedCollection != null && pagedCollection.MorePagesAvailable);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The getMemberObjects API returns all groups (transitive) of which the user is a member: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835117.aspx  . Also, using the checkMemberGroups API you can check whether or not the user is member of a group (transitively): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835107.aspx

However for your requirement the application roles feature of Azure AD might be a better fit. Your application can declare application roles, that can be assigned by the admin to users as well as groups. When the users signs in to your application, Azure AD computes the application roles that have been assigned to them and sends them in the roles claim. No need to query graph at runtime. See here: http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/

Comment: Your first suggestions worked for me.  Thank you.  We're not assigning roles directly in the azure application as our on-prem AD syncs to our azure AD and then we authenticate against the azure AD using OpenID back through our ADFS.  All of our groups/roles are managed in our on-prem AD.

Comment: " Your application can declare application roles, that can be assigned by the admin to users as well as groups"
This is gold!  

Why should an app developer meddle in someones AD bucket, checking for groups and worry about transitivity etc...  Will this work in multi-tenant?, that's the question..