# How to create AD nested groups using GraphServiceClient c#?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, active-directory-group, adgroup

Is it possible to create nested groups in Azure AD using Graph API client as:

[image]

Comment: I hope it helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200071/azure-ad-graph-api-user-memberof-nested-groups  @Kaishu

Comment: @Anshu This means we can create nested groups B and C members of A. But still, not clear about how we can reference/link B and C while creating them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `AdditionalData` to add members in the step of creating groups in C#.

> The [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2-create-a-group-with-owners-and-members) creates a Security group with an owner and members
> specified. Note that a maximum of **20** relationships, such as owners and
> members, can be added as part of group creation.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(clientId)
        .WithTenantId(tenantID)
        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
        .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

// Create group B and add members(user-id1 and user-id2)
var additionalDataGroupB = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {"members@odata.bind", new List<string>()}
};
(additionalData["members@odata.bind"] as List<string>).Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id1}");
(additionalData["members@odata.bind"] as List<string>).Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id2}");

var groupB = new Group
{
    Description = "Group B",
    DisplayName = "PamelaGroupB",
    GroupTypes = new List<String>()
    {
    },
    MailEnabled = false,
    MailNickname = "operations2019",
    SecurityEnabled = true,
    AdditionalData = additionalDataGroupB
};

Group groupBRequest = await graphClient.Groups.Request().AddAsync(groupB);
string groupB_id = groupBRequest.Id;

// Create group C
......
string groupC_id = groupCRequest.Id;


// Create group A and add members(groupB and groupC)
var additionalDataGroupA = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {"members@odata.bind", new List<string>()}
};
(additionalData["members@odata.bind"] as List<string>).Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/" + groupB_id);
(additionalData["members@odata.bind"] as List<string>).Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/" + groupC_id);

var groupA = new Group
{
    Description = "Group A",
    DisplayName = "PamelaGroupA",
    GroupTypes = new List<String>()
    {
    },
    MailEnabled = false,
    MailNickname = "XXXXX",
    SecurityEnabled = true,
    AdditionalData = additionalDataGroupA
};

await graphClient.Groups.Request().AddAsync(groupA);
```